# Error with creating an Array of JSON objects in swift

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am trying to parse a JSON string which is a collection of multiple 'Countries'. I have created a structure representing the fields in each JSON object and then one for the array. However I keep getting the following error

```
Error: cannot convert value of type 'CountryList' to specified type 'Country'
```

Here is my Code (written in Swift Playgrounds)

```
import Cocoa
let body = """
{"Countries":
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "USA",
    "capitalCity": 5,
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "France",
    "capitalCity": 5,
  }]}
""".data(using: .utf8)

struct Country: Codable {

    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let capitalCity: Int
 
    
}
struct CountryList: Codable {
    
    var Countries: [Country]
    
}



let countryJson: Country = try! JSONDecoder().decode(CountryList.self, from: body!)
print(countryJson)
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You have declared `countryJson` to be of type `Country`, but you are decoding `CountryList` - You want `let countryJson: CountryList = ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace this line

```
let countryJson: Country = try! JSONDecoder().decode(CountryList.self, from: body!)
```

with this:

```
let countryJson: CountryList = try! JSONDecoder().decode(CountryList.self, from: body!)
```

Comment: And you also do not need to explicitly declare the type, since it can be inferred.

Comment: You're right. It's not needed. But I always prefer leaving the type there in my code to make it clear for my fellow devs.